# Accessing class constants from instance stored in another class

Tags: php, oop, class, object, static

I have a class defined which has several constants defined through `const FIRST = 'something';

I have instantiated the class as `$class = new MyClass()`

then I have another class that takes a `MyClass` instance as one of it's constructors parameters and stores it as `$this->model = $myClassInstance;`

This works fine.

But I am wondering how I can access the constants from that instance?

I tried case `$this->model::STATE_PROCESSING` but my IDE tells me

> Incorrect access to static class member.

and PHP tells me

> unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in ...

I know I can do `MyClass::STATE_PROCESSING` but I am wondering if there is a way to get them based off the instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like your on an older version of php? PHP 5.3 allows the access of constants in the manner you describe... However, this is how you can do it without that inherent ability:

```
class ThisClass
{
    const FIRST = 'hey';

    public function getFIRST()
    {
        return self::FIRST;
    }
}

class ThatClass
{
    private $model;

    public function setModel(ThisClass $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getModel()
    {
        return $this->model;
    }
    
    public function Hailwood()
    {
        $test = $this->model;
        return $test::FIRST;
    }
}

$ThisObject = new ThisClass();
echo $ThisObject ->getFIRST(); //returns: hey
echo $ThisObject ::FIRST; //returns: hey; PHP >= 5.3

// Edit: Based on OP's comments
$ThatObject= new ThatClass();
$ThatObject->setModel($Class);
echo $ThatObject->getModel()->getFIRST(); //returns: hey
echo $ThatObject->Hailwood(); //returns: hey
```

Basically, were creating a 'getter' function to access the constant. The same way you would to externally access private variables.

See the OOP Class Constants Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php

Comment: Yes, that works, but try creating `ThatClass` and storing a reference to $Class in `ThatClass` then try access the `ThisClass` constants using that reference!

Comment: @Hailwood I've edited my answer based on your comments. Check it out. Works as intended on my machine. Let me know how else I can assist.

Comment: Try replacing this line `$this->model = $model;` with `$this->model::FIRST` that's the issue, I need to access it from inside the class, which is where is falls over for me.

Comment: @Hailwood I created a new function `Hailwood()` in `ThatClass`, which does your `$this->model::FIRST` by assigning `$this->model` to a variable first. Works.

Comment: Odd, I have no idea what it was then! ah well, if this works I 'spose I shall accept it!

Comment: your edited example with ThatClass is not showing up in the answer.