# Accessing static method of class object

Tags: php, oop

I'm having a very strange syntax error inside of a class when trying to access a static method of a class variable.

```
class VendorImport {
    //$factory is an instance of another class with a static method get()
    protected $factory;

    public function getInstance() {
        //method 1 works
        $factory = $this->factory;
        return $factory::get();

        //method 2 throws a syntax error
        return $this->factory::get();
    }
}
```

What is the proper syntax for method 2?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: vague guess: parser precedence problem, where your error version is seen as `$this->{factory::get()}`. What is the EXACT error message you're getting?

Comment: please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638014/accessing-class-constants-from-instance-stored-in-another-class

Comment: If I try it, I get `"syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)"`, which is very clear but doesn't explain the reason.

Comment: sorry, the actual error is FatalErrorException: Parse: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Comment: mesutozer I'm using PHP 5.4.26 so that question shouldn't apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use regular syntax for calling non-static methods - it's applicable for static ones too:

```
// instead of `return $this->factory::get();`
return $this->factory->get();
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/299P85). There's a drawback, though: now it's not obvious a static method gets called here. But then again, one cannot define two methods - static and non-static - under the same name in the same class.

Comment: This indeed does work but I hate that it doesn't make it obvious that I am calling a static method.  The question remains, why does $this->factory::get() caused a syntax error.  I am using PHP 5.4.